# Eclipse BIRT 2.6.0 P2 Update site?

Tags: eclipse, p2, helios

I just updated my eclipse to the new Helios SR1 version and now my reporting version is 2.6.1. But I need to use version 2.6.0 to make an older application work.

Is it possible to add an eclipse helios update site that contains the 2.6.0 version without installing the "old" version of eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The third digit change usually means bug fixes without breaking compatibility. Anyway, you can download archived versions from this site, and install them manually:

http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php?build=R-R1-2_6_0-201006171315